# как получить требуемые свойства в Observercollection

Tags: c#, json, uwp

**В примерах новые элементы добавляются в Observercollection вручную, проблема в том, что я хочу добавить данные из моего rootobject, где все они существуют и читаются из Json.**

**Main Page**

```
    ObservableCollection<Class1> rootobject { get; set; }
  
    Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
    public Detail detail { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string FilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Class1.json");
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
        {
            var json = file.ReadToEnd();
            rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Class1>>(json);
            //Color c = new Color();
            var items = new List<Class1>();

            items.Add(new Detail
            {
                icon_url = ?,
            });

            items.Add(new Gradient_Props
            {
                gradient_stop_1 = ?,
                gradient_stop_2 = ?,
            });

           
        }
       

    }
```

**Class created special JSON as Class**

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Detail[] details { get; set; }
       
    }
    public class Detail : Class1
    {
        public string detail_type { get; set; }
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string fill_color { get; set; }
        public Gradient_Props gradient_props { get; set; }
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public string resource_url { get; set; }
    }
    public class Gradient_Props : Class1
    {
        public string gradient_stop_1 { get; set; }
        public string gradient_stop_2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Color : Class1
    {
        public Color(string color)
        {
            color = this.title;
        }
    }
    public class Icon : Class1
    {
        public Icon(Detail[] iconUrl)
        {
            iconUrl = this.details;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Привязывайтесь к этому свойству и выводите. Я же вам сказал "Почитайте про UWP, прочитайте про привязки, вам же легче будет!"

Comment: про привязки  я прочитал,но конечно еще нужно примери посмотреть и такое что было бы более понятным но  мне нужно что бы я получил нужные свойства из json  дал им определеный тип который я создал и все использовать через DataTemplateSelector @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Для начала, я вам очень сильно советую сделать грамотную структуру вашего проекта, обдумать как и что должно быть, например, зачем вам `DataTemplateSelector`? Зачем вы делаете `Detail : Class1` (наследование)? Зачем `using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))`?  Ну и зачем `var items = new List<Class1>();`? Про привязки вы явно не читали, ибо "привязаться можно только к публичным свойствам", где у вас публичное свойство?

Comment: 1. сделать грамотную структуру вашего проекта.Что вы имеете в виду? Пишите более четко
2.DataTemplateSelector для перемещения для контроля управления
3.Detail : Class1 если не наследование то были проблеми и кое какие свойства получили null
4.using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath)) для чтения файла json
5.var items = new List<Class1>();  Здесь для использования observercollection 

Понятно что не все идеально написанно но питаюсь понять и что-то изменить @EvgeniyZ

Comment: 1. Я максимально четко и написал, у вас "кривая" структура проекта, вы топчитесь на месте, не понимая как должно и что надо делать. 2. Какого перемещения, о чем речь? 3. Это костыль из за неверной структуры данных. 4 `.DeserializeObject<...>(File.ReadAllText("Class1.json"));` 5. Как это относится к `ObserverCollection`?

Comment: ОК тогда как всю изменить или именно какой пример смотреть что было би чуть проще @EvgeniyZ?

Comment: Вот я вам [набросал](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xjdLIE) десериализацию вашего JSON и получение нужных данных из него. Сравните с тем, что у вас сейчас. Классы сгенерировал при помощи [этого](https://app.quicktype.io?share=aw30bDtb0gmhBQLCkTie) ресурса, он там выдал немного лишнего, но может быть полезного для вас (конверторы), на их основе вы можете сделать вовсе разделение данных на классы (что будет правильней) и вам не придется  таскать NULL объекты, которые не предназначены например для градиента.

Comment: Имея такую простую структуру вы можете уже делать что вам надо, к примеру нам нужны все градиенты и только их цвета. Делаем такое: `var allGradient = json.SelectMany(x => x.Details).Where(x=>x.DetailType == TypeEnum.Gradient).Select(x=> new { First = x.GradientProps.GradientStop1, Second = x.GradientProps.GradientStop2 });`, что даст удобный список градиентов со значениями `First` и `Second`, в которых будут цвета. Так что, как видите, читаемая и понятная структура данных, это удобно. Вам остается лишь это привязать куда надо, а для этого читайте про привязки!!