# Нужно реализовать DataTemplateSelector в uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

Пытаюс дабавить сюда часть кода где по клику на определеный тип на ListView будет отображаться элементы этого типа после долгих поиcков наконец смог получить все нужные  данные из JSON. теперь все подряд могу показывать на ListView но хочу сделать по нажатию на элемент думаю использовать SelectedItem https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz

```
**MainPage**

        public Class1[] RootObject { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Class1> roots { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();

        public Detail[] Title { get; set; }
        //public  Detail[] roots { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = roots;
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Class1.json");
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
            {
                var json = file.ReadToEnd();
                RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);

                foreach (var item in RootObject)
                {
                    foreach (var a in item.details)
                    {
                        if (a.detail_type == "Pattern")
                        {
                            roots.Add(new Icon
                            {
                                icon_url = a.icon_url
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var i in item.details)
                    {
                        if (i.detail_type == "Color")
                        {
                            roots.Add(new Color
                            {
                                fill_color = i.fill_color
                            });
                        }
                        else if (i.detail_type == "Gradient")
                        {
                            roots.Add(new Gradient_Props
                            {
                                gradient_stop_1 = i.gradient_props.gradient_stop_1,
                                gradient_stop_2 = i.gradient_props.gradient_stop_2

                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                itemGridView.ItemsSource = roots;

**DataTemplateSelector**
 public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate ColorTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate IconTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate Gradient_Template { get; set; }
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is Icon)
                return IconTemplate;
            if (item is Color)
                return ColorTemplate;
            if (item is Gradient_Props)
                return Gradient_Template;
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
        }

    }
**json**

[
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "type":  "Color",
        "title": "gen_color",
        "details": [
    
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#feffdf"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fdffab"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fff9af"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f9ff21"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffd933"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffbd39"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff8000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f05a28"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f12d2d"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#defcfc"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#a6e3e9"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#7efaff"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#53cde2"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#26baee"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#2470a0"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#235784"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#1b3764"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#4a0e5c"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#5e227f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#a8026f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#d22780"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff5da2"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fa67ab"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f48fb1"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f9a1bc"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#c7f2e3"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#9ed9c5"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#73dbc4"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#1abb9c"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#219897"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#155e63"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#00454a"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#003545"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#28544b"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#227066"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#4a772f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#7cbd1e"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "title": "effect_color_gradient",
        "details": [
        
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#002092",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#1AB9C8"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#F75070",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFE194"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#2B0096",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#E9649B"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#5A63D8",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#CD90E1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FDE869",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#00B1C1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FECF60",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#974EF6"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FFD529",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FD8440"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#C24078",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFC3B9"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#00EAF8",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#6D42EF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FF90D3",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#3AEF3C"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FFCD2C",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF0663"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FC1E50",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#D2B0EF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#EF14C5",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFC160"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#7AE4FF",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FC2F5D"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#6CF6DA",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#176DA0"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FF0467",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FC7437"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FD8041",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF4CA1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FEB984",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF5542"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#00FAC1",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#C500E1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#6FFF00",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#005BFF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#F8A2ED",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#934EAE"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#5F86EC",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#7C4CB0"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#EB4B92",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#CA76E3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "title": "win_pattern",
        "details": [
        
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_1.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_2.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_3.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_4.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_4.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_5.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_5.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_6.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_6.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_7.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_7.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_8.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_8.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_9.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_9.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_10.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_10.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_11.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_11.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_12.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_12.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_13.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_13.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_14.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_14.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_15.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_15.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_16.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_16.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_17.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_17.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_18.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_18.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_19.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_19.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_20.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_20.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]


**Model Json On C#**
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Detail[] details { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{itemType}{type}{title}{details}";
        }
    }
    public class Detail : Class1
    {
        public string detail_type { get; set; }
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string fill_color { get; set; }
        public Gradient_Props gradient_props { get; set; }
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public string resource_url { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{detail_type}{title}{type}";
        }
    }
    public class Color : Detail
    {
        public Color()
        {

        }
        public Color(string color)
        {
            this.fill_color = color;
        }
    }
    public class Icon : Detail
    {
        public Icon()
        {

        }
        public Icon(string icon)
        {
            this.icon_url = icon;
        }
    }
    public class Gradient_Props : Class1
    {
        public string gradient_stop_1 { get; set; }
        public string gradient_stop_2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: А смысл вам указывать меня, если вы меня не слушаете? Я вам дал структуру классов, в которые должны были JSON данные десериализоваться, вы же используете свою, кривую, с наследованием. Я вам сказал, что вам стоит почитать про привязки, как они работают, понять их суть, но нет, вы пишете `itemGridView.ItemsSource = roots;`, ну хоть про `ObservableCollection` услышали и на том спасибо, но что вы дальше от меня хотите то? Получилось вывести, молодцы, но `хочу сделать по нажатию на элемент`- это не вопрос, а "хотелка", которая лично мне не понятна..

Comment: Дело не в том что я так хочу просто задача так поставлена, насчет класса я благодарен просто не смог через него сделать наследование делаю для таго что бы каждому элементу например Color_у или Icon_у в новом листе дать определеный тип ото Selector не понимает что и как  возврашать про привязки я прочитал и они тут работают. itemGridView.ItemsSource = roots

Comment: `itemGridView.ItemsSource = roots` - это не привязка. Привязка, это когда вы можете без труда удалить все в XAML и у вас запуститься проект. У вас же идет просто указания данных контролу. То есть у вас должно быть не `<TextBox Name="textBox1" />` и далее `textBox1.Text = "Привет мир!"`, а `public string Text {get; set;} = "Привет мир!";` и `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>` (в UWP названия другие, но суть та-же).

Comment: По поводу JSON, я ведь вам [показал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173816#comment2040201_1173816) как без наследования и прочего определить какой тип, а также сказал " полезного для вас (конверторы), на их основе вы можете сделать вовсе разделение данных на классы (что будет правильней)". Вот вы просто ответьте на вопрос, зачем вашему градиенту содержать в себе все из `Class1` (`itemType`, `type` и др.)? Есть-ли это в самом JSON? Я лично не вижу.

Comment: `задача так поставлена` - это мы с вами уже выяснили, я [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174390#comment2041631_1174390) как я бы сделал, что у вас предположительно не так. Сейчас вы пишете, что у вас все работает и вы можете свободно вывести данные, тогда в чем вопрос? Чего вы хотите по клику-то делать? Если у вас данные отобразились с нужными шаблонами, тогда наверно у вас все работает и `DataTemplateSelector` сделал свою "магию", верно? Так что возвращаемся к первому комментарию и... `это не вопрос, а "хотелка", которая лично мне не понятна..`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ скорее всего я вам свою задачу обяснял не правильно, она поставлена следуюшим образом что по клику  на отделном LisView где будут Color ,Gradient, Icon  Selector  показывал только элементы этого типа . и да огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Ну тогда вы изначально не так решаете эту задачу. `DataTemplateSelector`, это лишь механизм определения вида объекта по определенным критериям, не более. Допустим у вас есть не знаю, To-Do лист и вы хотите сделать так, чтоб ваши кулинарные рецепты отображали поля для ввода "Название", "Кол-во", "Ингредиент", а ваш список фильмов для просмотра имел поля "Название", "Описание", "Рейтинг", ну может "Постер". Вот вы при помощи `DataTemplateSelector` можете это сделать. А ваша задача не про это, она про группировку объектов и их вывод.

Comment: Смотрите как сделал-бы я... У вас в JSON есть уже разбитие по группам, вам надо лишь данные от туда преобразовать в классы, отдельные классы, которые будут отвечать за что-то свое (цвет, изображения, градиент). Как только вы это сделаете, привязывайте к `ItemsControl` (или к его аналогам) не коллекцию градиентов, а коллекцию групп из [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHbvB.png), которые в свою очередь уже содержат необходимые объекты во внутренней коллекции `details`. А далее уже просто [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553) способом выводите данные в UI.